# XML comments generator for VS 2008

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, documentation

I am looking for XML comment generator like GhostDoc for VS 2008. I am looking for open source tool. Is there any Resharper- plug-in for generating XML comments?

Comment: Why don't you want to use GhostDoc?

Comment: According to http://submain.com/products/ghostdoc.aspx GhostDoc supports VS2008 and is still free, is there a particluar reason why you need it to be OS as well?

Comment: @ Steve: I want to use it for commercial purpose.

Comment: Isn't my suggestion (StyleCop for ReSharper) what you wanted?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, there is: [StyleCop for ReSharper](http://stylecopforresharper.codeplex.com/). Among a lot of other stuff, it can automatically create comments when you clean your code.

Comment: StyleCop can be used to generate comments? - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/StyleCop

Comment: Well, I should have been more specific. Clicking the link however would have solved the confusion :)

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [Sandcastle](http://sandcastle.codeplex.com/). It might be what you are looking for, at least it is open source.

Comment: Sandcastle wil extract comments, it won't create them.

Answer (score 0):

It's not open source, but my addin, [AtomineerUtils](http://www.atomineerutils.com/) may suit your needs. It's similar in concept to GhostDoc, but way more powerful and configurable, so it may be able to be configured to achieve what you need without needing access to the source. If it doesn't do something you need, then just mail me - I don't turn down any reasonable feature requests and usually try to implement them as soon as I can.

Alternatively, if you want source code for something very basic in this direction that will get you started, you could take a look [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163757.aspx).